# Why Lambda never reach or close to the reserved concurrency? Want SQS triggers more Lambda function to process message concurrently

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I've set a Lambda trigger with a SQS Queue. Lambda's reserved concurrency is set to 1000. However, there are millions of messages waiting in the queue need to be processed and it only invokes around 50 Lambdas at the same time. Ideally, I want SQS to trigger 1000 (or close to 1000) Lambda functions concurrently. Do I miss any configuration in SQS or Lambda? Thank you for any suggestion.

[image: Lambda concurrency metrics]
[image: Lambda reserved concurrency setting]
[image: SQS messages]

Comment: Presumably this is a regular, non-FIFO SQS queue.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [AWS Lambda developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-scaling:%7E:text=For%20standard%20queues,simultaneously%20is%201%2C000.):

> ...Lambda increases the number of processes that are reading batches by **up to 60 more instances per minute**. The maximum number of batches that an event source mapping can process simultaneously is 1,000.

So the behavior that you encountered (only invokes around 50 Lambdas at the same time) is actually expected.

If you are not using already, I would suggest doing batch processing in your lambda (so you can process 10 messages per invocation). If that is still not enough, you can potentially create more queues and lambdas to divide your load (considering that order is not relevant in your case), or move away from it and start polling the queue directly with EC2/ECS (which can increase your costs considerably however).